# Bounding a picture inside a shape on a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, includegraphics, bounding-box

I have a `tikzpicture` tiled inside of a `tikzpicture` with the `shape` of a starburst as a central, repeating `node`.  I want to fill the starburst with a picture.  Normally, for a question here, I'd take the starburst out of the tiling and have a much simpler MWE.  However, I do not want work-around solutions that are incompatible with tiling using an `\sbox`.  I have this which produces a starburst in a tiling as expected:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\newsavebox{\tileone}
\sbox{\tileone}{\let\newpage\relax%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.975cm,y=0.975cm]
    \clip (0,0.15) rectangle (2,2.15);
    \foreach \x in {0,1} {
            \foreach \y in {0,1} {
                \node[]  at (2*\x, 2*\y)
                { \includegraphics[width=0.065\textwidth]{globe.png}};
            \node[shape=starburst, fill=yellow, draw=red, very thin, rotate=10,
                /pgf/starburst point height=0.25cm, line width=0.25pt,
                minimum height=1.20cm, minimum width=1.20cm, name=ystar
                ] at (2*\x+1, 2*\y+1) {  };
                }
        }
    \begin{scope}[dashed,black]
        \draw plot (\x,\x-1);
        \draw plot (\x,\x+1);
        \draw plot (\x,-\x+1);
        \draw plot (\x,-\x+3);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.0cm, y=1.0cm] 
        \tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\tiny]
    
        \path[draw,fill tile picture={\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,
                                    fill=blue!40!yellow, rounded corners=0.5ex]
                             {\scalebox{0.5}{\usebox{\tileone}}};
                                    }, rounded corners=1ex]  (0.0, 0.0) rectangle (4.0, 4.0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Starburst in a tiling]

When I replace `] at (2*\x+1, 2*\y+1) {  };` with `] at (2*\x+1, 2*\y+1) {path picture bounding box.center={\node {\includegraphics[width=0.065\textwidth]{Fireball.png} } } };`, I get an error message that `path picture` is an undefined control sequence even though the `Tikz & PGF manual` for `Version 2.10-cvs` says that nodes are placed on paths.  When I substitute `ystar.center` for `path picture bounding box.center`, I get another undefined control sequence error.

By substituting `\node at (2*\x+1, 2*\y+1) {\includegraphics[width=0.065\textwidth]{Fireball.png}};` for the entire starburst node, I can get this, but the picture is already in the shape of a circle, and I want a starburst.

[image: Fiery Circle]

Lastly, I can draw a shape and use that bounding box to trim the picture, but I don't want to draw each segment of the starburst:

```
\draw[path picture={\node at (path picture bounding box.center) {
                              \includegraphics[height=2.50cm, trim=70 0 0 30, clip]
                                      {Fireball.png} };}, 
      draw=blue, thick] (2*\x+1, 2*\y+1) -- ++ (0,0.75) -- ++ (0.75, 0) -- cycle;
```

Not the actual shape I'll use, but this process does trim a picture by the shape.

**Other Answers**

This talks about `shapes` inside of a node, but I want a shape to act as a bounding box for a picture inside of a node. [TikZ: Different shapes inside of a node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566064/tikz-different-shapes-inside-of-a-node)

This shows how to fill a (drawn) rectangle with a picture, but as I've said above, I'm not looking to draw a shape.  I want use a shape from a shape library: [How to create a rectangle filled with image using TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219356/how-to-create-a-rectangle-filled-with-image-using-tikz)

This addresses a particular feature of drawing a rectangle to use to trim a picture, but not what I want: [How to create a rectangle filled with image using TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219356/how-to-create-a-rectangle-filled-with-image-using-tikz)

This talks about including graphics in a node, not the bounding box issue: [Moving a picture inside a scope on a background layer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511380/moving-a-picture-inside-a-scope-on-a-background-layer)

This is close, but does not include the bounding aspect, which is really what is tripping me up: [How to typeset a TikZ picture inside a node?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47359/how-to-typeset-a-tikz-picture-inside-a-node)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is just where you tried to place `path picture`. It should be into `node` options not as node contents.

I don't have `globe` or `Fireball` images, but as you can see, the result keeps the `star`node shape.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\newsavebox{\tileone}
\sbox{\tileone}{\let\newpage\relax%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.975cm,y=0.975cm]
    \clip (0,0.15) rectangle (2,2.15);
    \foreach \x in {0,1} {
            \foreach \y in {0,1} {
                \node[]  at (2*\x, 2*\y)
                { \includegraphics[width=0.065\textwidth]{example-image-A}};
            \node[shape=starburst, fill=yellow, draw=red, very thin, rotate=10,
                /pgf/starburst point height=0.25cm, line width=0.25pt,
                minimum height=1.20cm, minimum width=1.20cm, name=ystar,
                path picture={\node at (path picture bounding box.center) {\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-B}};}
                ] at (2*\x+1, 2*\y+1) {  };
                }
        }
    \begin{scope}[dashed,black]
        \draw plot (\x,\x-1);
        \draw plot (\x,\x+1);
        \draw plot (\x,-\x+1);
        \draw plot (\x,-\x+3);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.0cm, y=1.0cm] 
        \tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\tiny]
    
        \path[draw,fill tile picture={\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,
                                    fill=blue!40!yellow, rounded corners=0.5ex]
                             {\scalebox{0.5}{\usebox{\tileone}}};
                                    }, rounded corners=1ex]  (0.0, 0.0) rectangle (4.0, 4.0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]